# How Do I Clear the List of the Output of system()?

Tags: ruby, macos, vim

I've been told that the output of `system()` is stored in a temporary file.

I'm getting this error when I run the command, and it's `system()` that's causing it:

```
let content_type = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
let accept = 'Accept: application/json'
let url = g:languagetool_server_root . '/v2/check'
Calling shell to execute: "(curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "language='en-US'&enabledOnly=false&data='%7B%22annotations%22%3A
%5B%7B%22markup%22%3A%22%3Ch1%3E%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%22Hello+world%21%22%7D%2C%7B%22markup%22%3A%22%3C%2Fh1%3E%22%7D%2C%7B%22markup%22%3A%22%3Cp%3E%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%22Style+and+grammer+checke
r%22%7D%2C%7B%22markup%22%3A%22%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%5D%7D'"'http://localhost:8081/v2/check'")>/var/folders/yh/z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000gn/T/vzsapcl/2 2>&1"
Error detected while processing function languagetool#CheckGrammar:
line   12:
E282: Cannot read from "/var/folders/yh/z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000gn/T/vzsapcl/2"
```

I just noticed that the path that the error gives is appended to `system()`. It's weird. Here are the codes that runs the shell command:

```
let content_type = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
let accept = 'Accept: application/json'
let url = g:languagetool_server_root . '/v2/check'
let response = system('curl -X POST --header ' . shellescape(content_type) . ' --header ' . shellescape(accept) . ' -d language=' . shellescape(g:languagetool_default) . '&enabledOnly=false&data=' . shellescape(json) . shellescape(url))
```

I've tried `:clear` so far and `histdel()` but I was told `histdel()` has nothing to do with the temporary files of the output of `system()`.

Comment: No. You have been told that the system() calls are not cached. You don't have a caching problem, you have temporary file problem.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I'll correct it.

Comment: We need both the error message AND the code that presumably caused the error AND some context. Here is a wild hypothesis: your call is asynchronous but system() is synchronous and the temporary file it uses doesn't exist at the time.

Comment: It's in the question. I used `:set verbose=5` to log the process and error.

Answer (score 0):

It worked! I reconstructed the curl command and separated the header and body (including the data to be passed) into variables. It was an issue with quotation marks. `shellescape()` encloses the value of the variable with single quotation marks.

This is the code that worked:

```
let content_type = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
let accept = 'Accept: application/json'
let data = 'language=' . g:languagetool_default . '&enabledOnly=false&data=' . json
let url = g:languagetool_server_root . '/v2/check'
let response = system('curl -s -X POST --header ' . shellescape(content_type) . ' --header ' . shellescape(accept) . ' -d ' . shellescape(data) . ' ' . shellescape(url))
```

I still don't understand why there was a temporary file being loaded by `system()` that doesn't exist, though. It's definitely not `curl` because it doesn't store the output anywhere client-side.

---

I spoke too soon. It's doing it again in the reconstructed `curl` command. I guess it wasn't the issue with the quotation mark that was causing the issue with the temporary files.

---

My bad. It's not related to this question.